# How do I do this NSPredicate code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm having trouble with NSPredicate. I have a core data object called Entry, which contains an NSDate called creationDate. I want to compare this to the variable I have called date.

I'm using an NSDate category to pull out the individual year of both objects, and a core data category to perform a predicate on all Entry objects in my core data store.

```
[Entry allForPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"creationDate.year == %i",  date.year]];
```

I think this is wrong, as it's not giving me the result I expect, and is instead turning up blank.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt, Core Data can incorporate Categories when it creates the raw database call.

For your case create 2 dates, one with January the 1st this year at 0:00 and one year later

```
 NSString *basePredicateString = @"creationDate >= %@ AND creationDate < %@";
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:basePredicateString, startDate, endDate];
```

for the sake of completeness — How I would generate the start & end date for the actual year:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit startDate:&startDate interval:NULL forDate:startDate];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
comps.year = 1;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:startDate options:0];
```

In the comments below this answer, jbrennan proposed, that indeed a category can be incorperated into a predicate. While he is right for collections as NSArrays (he added a link to a test project), it does not work when it comes to Core Data fetch requests — at least I cannot make it work. I tried. Here is my test: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/CoreDataCategoryTest

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *can* incorporate category methods. At least, I've done almost exactly this when using `NSFetchedResultsController` and a category method on `NSDate`.

Comment: The predicates will follow keypaths of the objects using the dot, so as long as the category has `-key` then `date.key` evaluates.

Comment: you are using the predicate with a plain array — but will it work with core data?

Comment: anyway — I need to go to bed, my city is already awaking. I will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

@vikingosegundo has the right answer - you can't use categories in a predicate.

If you understand SQL, try setting the following "**Argument passed on launch**":

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`

this will allow you to see the SQL generated by the request. This should help you see how the predicate you write is translated into SQL.

---

**Edit** Per @vikingosegundo again - the above applies when used with CoreData per the OP's question.