# NSPredicate filtered by year moth day

Tags: ios, date, core-data, nspredicate

I use Core Data for storing my data model objects. Each object has NSDate property.

NSDate property has format like below:

```
2013-03-18 12:50:31 +0000
```

I need to create predicate that will fetch my objects just by this value `2013-03-18` without time.

Comment: NSString *searchText =@"2013-03-18";
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@",searchText];
        NSMutableArray *predarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[totalArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
        if (predarr.count>0)
        {
// Write your loic
}

Comment: `NSDate` objects do not have format, if write their `description` somewhere, the format depends on the device (iOs) configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your dates are stored as actual dates then you should use that to your advantage and not fiddle with formats. You can simply create a predicate that checks that if the dates is between two dates (with times). The first date is your date with the time 00:00:00 and the second date is one day after that.

```
// Create your date (without the time)
NSDateComponents *yourDate = [NSDateComponents new];
yourDate.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
yourDate.year  = 2013;
yourDate.month = 3;
yourDate.day   = 18;
NSDate *startDate = [yourDate date];

// Add one day to the previous date. Note that  1 day != 24 h
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
oneDay.day = 1;
// one day after begin date
NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:oneDay 
                                                                toDate:startDate
                                                               options:0];

// Predicate for all dates between startDate and endDate
NSPredicate *dateThatAreOnThatDay = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", 
                                     startDate, 
                                     endDate]];
```

Comment: +1 for being faster than me and for the *Note that  1 day != 24 h* comment

Comment: @vikingosegundo was it your answer here with the same logic but `oneDay.year = 1` ? :)

Comment: @A-Live, yes, I edited the code I had posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954273/how-do-i-do-this-nspredicate-code/10954503#10954503

Comment: I added a answer similar to this but with another way of creating the dates.

Comment: Remark: `[yourDate date]` works only if you have assigned a calendar to the NSDateComponents, otherwise it returns nil (at least in my test program).

Comment: @MartinR I didn't run that part of the code. Good catch. I've updated the code

Comment: But if we want NSPredicate filtered by year moth only then what should do for that.

Answer (score 4):

While David showed how you can create a predicate, i want to add a easier way to generate a date for 0:00

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval lengthDay;

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                startDate:&startDate
                                 interval:&lengthDay 
                                  forDate:startDate];
```

`startDate` now contain a date representing `0:00` for the current time zone of today

```
NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthDay];
```

Now we can put it into the predicate

```
NSPredicate *daySpanPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

<sub>Thanks to [MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) for the improvement.</sub>

Comment: The calculation of `startOfTomorrow` could be simplified slightly by using the `interval` parameter in `rangeOfUnit:...` and adding that to `startOfToday`. Then you don't need any date components at all. Is that correct?

Comment: @MartinR, time intervals aren't aware of DST and leap seconds.

Comment: What I meant is: `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfToday interval:&lengthOfToday forDate:startDate];` `NSDate *startOfTomorrow = [startOfToday dateByAddingTimeInterval:lengthOfToday];` - I made a quick test with 31.03.2013 (start of DST in Germany, as you know), and `lengthOfToday` was correctly set to 23 hours.

Comment: Interesting, seems as if I misunderstood the purpose of the interval parameter.

Comment: but: it doesnt catch leap seconds. at least the 4 last occurrences I tested.

Comment: Do you have an example date where your and my calculation of `startOfTomorrow` give different results?  (Note that there is an error in your code, `startDate` should be `startOfToday`.)

Comment: I didnt compare our codes. I just tried your code with days that had a leap second added, taken from http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaltsekunde

Comment: I tested with 30.06.2012, and both methods gave the same result. The "Date and Time Programming Guide" makes some remarks about leap seconds being ignored, but I don't know if this applies here.

Comment: Anyway: Danke! Wieder etwas gelernt!