# NSFetchRequest for a specific Month and Year

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to setup an NSFetchRequest which looks for an entry which matches the given month and year.

The Data is stored as NSDate. I'm wondering now how can I get the components out of it for a fetch request?

Comment: Here is the answer of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500166/nspredicate-filtered-by-year-moth-day

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski Good link. See my comment. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience I would create two different attributes for handling this.

In your entity create `month` and `year` of type int and check again those. Your predicate will be simple and the request will be also fast.

You will populate them at taking the components from your date.

**P.S.** I'm not aware of other possible solutions, so also wait for other replies. This is my personal solution for achieving this.

Credits goes to **@MartinR**. His comment was absolutely correct.

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski's link is really valid. ;)

Comment: I give you the checkmark because yours works as well ;)

Comment: @flexaddicted: Note that you cannot fetch based on transient attributes, so not storing `month` and `year` in the store will not work.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, my fault. I will update my reply to fit this. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR I added credits for your comment ;)