# Fetching results the current day & all years?

Tags: ios, xcode, date, core-data, nspredicate

I've read through many posts and tried many different things but I can't seem to find something that works for what seems like it should be simple.  Maybe I'm just missing it!

I converted an extensive list of names and birthdays from .json into sqlite.  I'm trying to fetch all the results for the current day (i.e. all birthdays that happened on March 20th in my database).  I believe I'm looking for a predicate to use in my fetchedresultscontroller.

Is is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500166/nspredicate-filtered-by-year-moth-day

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: That link does *not answer* this question. That is about finding all objects for one specific day (e.g. March 20th 2013). It does not give a method to find all objects for March 20th for *all* years.

Comment: @MartinR: But that will lead to the answer, bit similar, I thought.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I don't think so, at least I don't see how to use the code of that answer. You would have to compute `startDate` and `endDate` for *all years* that are possible, and combine all these to a predicate.

Comment: Voted for reopen. As I understand it, the OP is asking for a method to fetch all Core Data entries having a date attribute that falls onto a particular day/month in any year. That sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1):

If the birthday is stored as `NSDate` in the database, then I don't know a easy solution.

But for a birthday it perhaps makes more sense to store it as three attributes "year", "month", "day". (NSDate is an absolute point of time, which may be March 20th in one part of the world and March 19th in a different part of the world.)

If you do that, you can simple use

```
int theMonth = 3;
int theDay = 20;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"month = %d AND day = %d", theMonth, theDay]
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will give that a try today.

Comment: @user2193664: You are welcome. Let me know if you need more information.