# Search CoreData for Matching NSDate - Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsdate, nspredicate

I want to search through all existing objects to see if there are any matching date objects in CoreData:

Dates are currently saved in my CoreData via the **start_date** attribute with the following format: 2013-08-29 14:27:47 +0000.

I am then letting a user select a date from a UIDatePicker and assigning .date() to variable **date**.

e.g. My Selected **date** = 2013-08-29 17:34:23 +0000.

Below is how i search CoreData, using a predicate.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "start_date contains[search] %@", date)
let request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Project")
let sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "number", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptorsAry:NSArray = [sortDescriptor]
request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorsAry
request.predicate = predicate

return request
```

However i get no results. I assume this because both attributes don't match because of the time:

> start_date = 2013-08-29 14:27:47 +0000
>
> date       = 2013-08-29 17:34:23 +0000

How can i some how tell CoreData to ignore the "177:34:23 +0000" bit, or is there a better way?

Edit:

I do have the option to change the way in which the date format is stored initially:

I have tried this:

```
    var now:NSDate = self.startDatePicker.date
    var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
    var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: now)
    components.hour = 00
    components.minute = 00
    components.second = 00
    var newDate:NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

However on some days, my time is being set to a day before.
For Example:

Selecting the 30th August, after transform I get 2014-08-29 23:00:00 +0000

Comment: Question: do you need to save in your Core Data `start_date` attribute a `NSDate` with this format `2013-08-29 17:34:23 +0000` or is it possible to change your model and save a `NSDate` with this format: `2013-08-29 00:00:00 +0000`?

Comment: @POB It is possible for me to change the way the date format is saved initially in core data.

Comment: I have a doubt. How can I translate your predicate? Is it: "retrieve all managedObjects that have a `start_date` that exactly match `date`" or is it "retrieve all managedObjects that have a `start_date` of type "day" and that contain/include `date`"?

Comment: @POB It should retrieve all managedObjects that have a start_date matching that day. So for example, I want to - retrieve all objects that have a start_date 01/01/2014 - the time it was done on shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have to option of changing the way you store data, I would store it on your project-entity as three attributes: an Integer for year, an Integer for month and an Integer for day. It will be easier to code (you can create a predicate like:

```
NSInteger year = ....
NSInteger month = ....
NSInteger day = ....    
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"day == %@  AND month == %@ and year == %@", @(day), @(month), @(year)];
```

) and this probably work quicker compared to using a string. If you want to go with the string (beware extraneous spaces or other interpunction!), you can in code construct a string with the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' (use NSString stringWithFormat:) and then use an NSPredicate like:

```
NSInteger year = ....
NSInteger month = ....
NSInteger day = ....    
NSString * dateString = [NSStringWithFormat: @"%4i-%2i-%2i", year, month, day];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"dateString contains %@", dateString];
```

However, this will only work if YOU constructed the string that you stored, not the NSDate.description(). If you store actual NSDate, see my first original answer :).

But really, if you still have an option, don't store it as a string. It wil really be problematic, if not now, then later (I can tell from experience).

Comment: I usually use a single integer for this: 10000*year + 100*month + day. So, 20140830 for today. Easy to compare and strictly ascending with time.

Comment: Ah this is very nice. It might have some implications, but i like it.

Answer (score 2):

Before to save `start_date` attributes in Core Data, you need to be sure that their time is set to 12:00 AM:

```
//Get "Aug 29, 2014, 12:00 AM" from "Aug 29, 2014, 10:07 PM"
let newDate = NSDate() //or any other date
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
var startDate: NSDate?
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: newDate)

//Create, set and save a new managedObject
//Records, here, is the name of your NSManagedObject subclass
let record = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Records", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Records
record.start_date = startDate
/* set other attributes here */

var error: NSError?
if !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    abort()
}
```

Then, you will be able to fetch a date in Core Data with the predicate you want this way:

```
//Set your datePicker date to 12:00 AM
let pickerDate = dateFromMyDatePicker //as NSDate
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
var predicateDate: NSDate?
var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, startDate: &predicateDate, interval: &duration, forDate: pickerDate)

//Create your fetchRequest
/* ... */
//Set your predicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "start_date == %@", predicateDate)
```

**Edit**

As an alternative to `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`, you can use the code you provide. But in both cases, don't forget to add the following line:

```
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

Comment: I tried this, however some of the dates read wrong. e.g. If i select the 30th August, it converts to the date 2014-08-29 23:00:00 +0000

Comment: Be careful: `2014-08-29 22:00:00 +0000` displayed in the debugger, `Aug 30, 2014, 12:00 AM` displayed in a Playground and `30/08/2014 00:00:00 UTC+2` displayed with a NSDateFormatter (dateStyle = .ShortStyle, timeStyle = .LongStyle) can represent the same NSDate (Paris, France UTC+2).

Answer (score 1):

```
<edit>
```

Your second way of doing things seems to me like a good way to go. Store the integer values for year, month and day, and create a predicate with that. Your usage of NSDateComponents and calendar is great, and so this should be the easiest way to go. Very important: don't use for the time of 00, as midnight is a tricky time (there is daylight savings times in parts of the world, there is the question of whether exactly midnight is part of the previous of the next day). Just enter 12 as the time, to be as far away as you can from midnight. 
Also, i would advice you to watch the WWDC from 2011 'Performing Calendar Calculations, Session 117. It talks among other very interesting things about why midnight is tricky (if not, then that is explained in the 2013 session :) ).

```
</edit>
```

NSDate has sub-second accuracy. It's description method (that gets called when you NSLog an NSDate) only displays second-accuracy.
So to use an NSDate in an NSPredicate, always specify 'larger/smaller then or equal to' operators.

For example:

```
NSDate * lastWeek = // ... created using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

NSPredicate * entitiesFromAfterLastWeekAndBeforeNow = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"start_date >= %@ AND start_date <= %@", lastWeek, now];
```

I would advice against storing a data in something else the a native NSDate, as you might store dates that are incorrect due to conversions. Also, storing dates as string will make queries a lot slower (as strings have to be parsed, and NSDate is simply a number). But that is another discussion, and you might want to ship, so you have to do what you think is best.

Edit: I'm sorry, only now noticed that you are writing Swift. But I think my example is clear enough that it is convertible to Swift, right?

Comment: Thanks, although I'm specifically trying to search for entities with a matching day, month, year. However, because the time (h:m:s) does not match up from the date the user selects (from UIDatePicker.date()) - and the .date() when the entity was created - i get no results.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think your second approach is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks, So now selecting August 30th gives me: 2014-08-30 11:00:00 +0000. So when I select August 30th from my DatePicker for searching let say 5 months from now, will it always be 2014-08-30 11:00:00 +0000 or  could it end up being 2014-08-30 12:00:00 +0000... in which case, wouldn't this break search? I assume it wouldn't but just double checking :)

Comment: Yes 5 months from now, you could end up with 11:00 or 13:00 instead of 12:00. But if you leave out the hours in your predicate, and construct your query with only year, month and day, then it will return you the correct results, as the day will not have changed when the hours fluctuate a couple of hours around noon. (Unless in exotic circumstances, as in Samoa for example an entire day was skipped some years ago :) ).

Comment: Also: do not forget that when you NSLog an NSDate it will print out the date as if you were in London without Daylight Savings Time at that moment. That is why you should convert it to NSDateComponents via an NSCalendar that has THE SAME locale set for storing and querying. When displaying the date, you can create another calendar, or NSDateFormatter, that handles the date differently. But once you store the dates using a certain NSCalendar+locale combination, stick with it forever.

Comment: Ok I understand now, you've been a great help. One more question though, how would you construct a query so that it would only check for year/month/day when  2013-08-29 11:00:00 +0000 is passed. I've looked here but they seem to be removing date : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500166/nspredicate-filtered-by-year-moth-day

Comment: I will add another anser, as it is too long for a comment.